# java.net.SocketException: Too many open files error in java 8 and wildfly

Tags: centos, java, ulimit, wildfly

We are using wildfly 8 with jdk version 1.8 in centos stream 8 for our application. Recently we have been facing like application stop responding and on same time we found "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files" error application log.

We have set ulimit set to 65536 (Verify by ulimit -n command). Also when we run lsof -p [PID] command we can get 1,99,794 requests for TCP connection (mentioned)

java    675641 root *732u     sock                0,9       0t0 3702183824 protocol: TCP

So what is the above connection meaning? As we have set ulimit to 65536 still how it is possible to use more connection by application. And how to troubleshoot "Too many open files" issue?

I appreciate your assistance in advance.